# Why does your character need to confirm multiple times before calling certain NPCs via their mobile in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm a totally blind player of GTA V. When using the mobile phone of any of the three characters to call another NPC, it only takes a single press on my controller to confirm my selection - however, when calling certain chars (as an example if Trevor chooses to call Michael), I've noticed that after selecting him, it takes several more button presses to confirm. Would somebody be able to let me know what gets displayed when initially selecting Trevor when playing as Michael, and any other options that are available from this screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure when you select Trevor as Michael it says 'hang out,' and once you select that I think you get to pick what you do when you 'hang out' such as going to the movies or playing tennis. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. A definitive answer on this would be amazing if somebody has the time to take a look for me. :)